# I have xepersian installed using miktex but Texstudio returns the error message it cannot find xepersian

Tags: packages, installing, xepersian

I use Miktex installation and have just installed Xepersian package. When I try
to compile a document using XeLatex that calls the Xepesian package I get the error 
messege "cannot find Xepersian.sty". The same issue happens with both TexStudio and
TexMaker. I want to eventually get Farsi documents compiled and get pdf output.
Any idea what is going on wrong?
Thank you for your time

Comment: I update Miktex in admin mode, only. Isn't that enough?

Comment: I will check if there is a problem with the newest update. Will need a few minutes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is here I'll delete my comments:-)

Comment: I used to use Texlive but could find and  install XePersian package in it so I uninstalled it and turned to Miktex. It has a nice package manager

Comment: xepersian is part of texlive (apart from a couple  of days last week)

Comment: there is a bug in the miktex xepersian package - it is completly empty. I will open an issue.

Comment: The problem I had with Texlive is that you don't know each individual package it contains

Comment: See https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/177. It should be repaired fast.

Comment: In texlive you only need to do `tlmgr install xepersian` to get it.

Comment: I am more of a user and not quite an expert and even didn't know the command you just mensioned

Comment: Thank you Ulrike and David for your time and valuable help. I would not find the issue by myself.